# How do i load json data only after a button is pressed in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want something similar to the tutorial in angularJS site but how do i make the data appear on the page only after a button is pressed?

Comment: There are a number of ways to build this behavior, so could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE

I see you've updated your question and want json data loaded on click:

**Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nWoSrGxU1yfO6mUhiyvx?p=preview**

**HTML** stays the same:

```
  <button ng-click="clickButton()">Click!</button>
  <div ng-bind="message"></div>
```

**JSON**: test.json file contains:

```
{"msg": "I AM A TEST MESSAGE" }
```

**Angular**: this is the most basic way to do it. You use $http and call it inside your `clickButton()` function:

```
var app = angular.module('myTestApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.clickButton = function() {
    $http.get('test.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data.msg;
      });
  }
  
}]);
```

Hope this helps.

---

You need to provide us with some more info + code so we know what you're exactly talking about. But the following is what i think you're after:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myTestApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <button ng-click="clickButton()">Click!</button>
   <div ng-bind="testMessage"></div>
</div>
```

**Angular**:

```
angular.module('myTestApp', [])
     .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.clickButton = function() {
           $scope.testMessage = "I AM A TEST MESSAGE";
        };
     })
```

**fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/crjLj/

Comment: @BASarat Why do you prefer ngBind?

Comment: Because it removes the flicker you see when angular is being loaded. Instead of `<span>{{prop}}</span>` initially rendering as `{{prop}}` before angular kicks in you can do `<span ng-bind="prop">whatever<span>` which renders as `whatever` till angular kicks in.

Comment: to remove the flicker, you can also add a style in your css called '.ng-cloak', and set it to "display:none;", then in your controller div, add the class in. This will trigger ng-cloak functionality and it'll display once angular is loaded.