# AngularJS : How to read data of JSON file on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to call a function on button click in which HTTP called to read data from JSON file , Following code is working fine when HTML loads the data from JSON file is loading on `<ul>` but I want to call function on button (Continue button) click , How can I achieve this? because when I encoded `http.get` method in a function and calls on button click it doesn't work .

**HTML**

```
 <label class="item">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="ForgotPasswordSubmit" type="submit"  ng-disabled="ForgotPasswordForm.$invalid" >Continue</button>

            </label>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in loginData">
        {{ x.result +','+ x.status}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**SignupCtrl.js**

```
use strict';
angular.module('User').controller('SignupCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$state', "SettingService", function($scope,$http, $state, SettingService) {

    /*LoginCtrl code will come here*/
    var vm = this;

 vm.signup = function(){
  $state.go('app.orderlist');
 };


 $http.get("forgotpassword.json").success(function (data) {
      $scope.loginData = data;

  });

}]);
```

Comment: it's bit hard to understand your requirement ,what you do mean by "Following code is working fine when HTML loads the data from JSON file is loading on <ul>"

Comment: I mean that The following code is working fine when the HTML page loads it reads data from json file and loads data in the list view 
But I want to do this on Button Click not on page load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i load json data only after a button is pressed in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703659/how-do-i-load-json-data-only-after-a-button-is-pressed-in-angularjs)

Comment: answer is given in answer column ,reply me if you still did n't understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the code inside a function and call the function on click using the ng-click directive.

```
vm.getData = function(){
  $http.get("forgotpassword.json").success(function (data) {
      $scope.loginData = data;

  });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="ForgotPasswordSubmit" type="submit" ng-click="vm.getData()"  ng-disabled="ForgotPasswordForm.$invalid" >Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thanks one more query is How can I display data which I fetch from JSoN file in HTML?

Comment: Thnakyou So much

Comment: why the answer is removed?

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.getData= function(){
$http.get("forgotpassword.json").success(function (data) {
  $scope.loginData = data;
 });
};
```

In html use

```
ng-click="vm.getData()"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your button like this

```
 <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="ForgotPasswordSubmit" type="button"  ng-disabled="ForgotPasswordForm.$invalid" 
ng-click="functionForLoadData()">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thanks one more query is How can I display data which I fetch from JSON file in HTML?

Comment: <h1 ng-repeat="x in DataArrayYouFetched">{{x}}</h1>

Comment: function is not calling on button click